# Eclipse CDT cannot parse methods on elements in STL containers

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Juno with CDT to develop my C++ project with custom makefile. I am also using C++11 features, which I got to work with Eclipse's parser following advice here on SO.

The problem is that Eclipse is unable to parse methods or fields accessed on STL container elements. E.g.:

*mainapp.h*

```
typedef struct _PlayerCalibrationData {
    [...]
    std::string getSamplesStr()
    {
            [...]
    }
} PlayerCalibrationData;

std::vector<MainApp::PlayerCalibrationData> m_calibrationData;
```

*mainapp.cpp*

```
m_calibrationData[0].getSamplesStr();
```

`getSamplesStr()` will be underlined and marked as an error, with the message "Method 'getSamplesStr' could not be resolved".

The compiler doesn't complain, though, regardless of whether I invoke it from Eclipse or from the command line.

Also, when I type `m_calibrationData.`, all vector methods pop up via content assist (i.e. it's not an issue of Eclipse not finding the vector include), but as soon as I access an element via `[]` or `at()`, content assist is quiet and anything typed manually is marked as an error.

Is it normal that this doesn't work? If yes, is there a way I can turn off assist/correction for template-based containers specifically?

**EDIT**

I now also tried disabling c++11 support, and if I do that the problem disappears -- but then of course the c++ 11 types and syntax aren't recognized.

**EDIT 2**

I imported a second project, entered exactly the same settings, and for this project the parsing works. The only difference is the project layout (different location of makefiles). But even if I delete and re-import the first project, it still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is most likely the same as [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=299124), although that's not for eclipse. I'd post a bug for cdt

Comment: Seems like CDT is not properly parsing the return value of `operator[]` for `std::vector`.  Do you also get errors like "Invalid arguments" for statements like `foo.push_back(m_calibrationData[0])`?  See [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349849)

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

"your project name" -> right click -> properties:

C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> switch to the tab named "Providers":

- for "Configuration" select "Release" (and afterwards "debug")
- switch off all providers and just select "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings"
- uncheck "Share setting entries between projects (global provider)"
- in the "Command to get compiler specs:" add "-std=c++11" without the quotes (may work with quotes too)
- hit apply and close the options
- rebuild the index

this works for me on both mashines, at home and at work
win7 x64, latest official eclipse with cdt
[mingw-w64 gcc 4.7.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/64-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x64-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev10.7z/download) from the mingwbuilds project on sourceforge

Comment: Sounds nice but doesn't work for me. I disabled all builders to solve an infinite rebuild loop problem earlier on.

Comment: Ugg, its ok now, so there's something in this answer after all =)